# UIScrollView: Only scroll when allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiresponder

I've been trying to only have my `UIScrollView` scroll in one direction and still get all `UITouch` events. I'm not fully sure this is possible, at all.

I've tried to override the `UIResponder`'s "touches" events, but as soon as the `UIScrollView` starts scrolling, the touches methods stop getting called.

I then tried setting the `UIScrollView`'s `scrollEnabled` property to false until I want the `UIScrollView` to begin receiving drag events, but I can't seem to find a way to have the `UIScrollView` to begin receiving touch events mid-drag. ***Is this possible?***

My next attempt was adding "padding" to the scroll view and creating my own "touch events" by playing around with the `contentOffset` property, but that started calling `scrollViewDidScroll:` an excessive amount of times and processing like crazy - also some issues with the validity of the responses.

I've played around with `hitTest:withEvent:`, `pointInside:withEvent:`, `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` without any success.

I've tried a few other things, since, but none have worked. Also, from what I've found, setting `delaysContentTouches` to false destroys the scroll response.

I would love some *real* overridden touches methods. Methods that if I don't call super, the `UIScrollView` doesn't receive the touches.

***I need a way to get `UITouch`es (Drags, begins, releases and cancels, not just taps), without affecting the scroll of the `UIScrollView`, since the `UIResponder` "touches" events drop off as soon as scrolling starts. Is this possible?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to detect common `touches`, try attaching `gesture recognizers` like `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `view`, they should work even with a `UIScrollView`.

You can also try placing a transparent `UIView` on top of the `scrollview` that detects some `touches` and passes the rest to the `scrollview`.

Comment: Passing the touches mid-drag doesn't allow the scroll view to scroll. Also, I'm not looking for taps, but touches of ALL events (especially the drags).

Comment: Then try making a custom gesture recognizer that catches the events you want. See this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: And this might be useful: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/9213-detect-touch-in-scrollview-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you, however, that second post is irrelevant. If you look [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/discussion/comment/100289/#Comment_100289), it stopped working in SDK 3.0. Unfortunately, I've already seen most of these things.

Comment: I've figured it out using a custom UIGestureRecognizer and implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you start to scroll save off a copy of the offset. Then check against it when you finish scrolling.  This code allows scrolling to the left but prevents it from scrolling right

```
CGPoint oldOffset;
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    oldOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < oldOffset.x) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:oldOffset];
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but I need the dragging touches. That will only give me the distance between the start and end points.